# Buddypress Group Activity Loop Filter activity type

Tags: android-activity, filter, buddypress

I'm using Buddypress 1.8.1

When the group home page load I want to show only **'activity_update'** and **'joined_group'** activities in Activity Loop.

Here is my Activity Loop code. It is standard loop code.

```
<?php if ( bp_has_activities( bp_ajax_querystring( 'activity' ) ) ) : ?>
    <?php while ( bp_activities() ) : bp_the_activity(); ?>

        <?php locate_template( array( 'activity/entry.php' ), true, false ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How to filter these activities in page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created this function in bp-custom.php page.

```
function filtering_activity_default( $query ) {
  if ( empty( $query ) && empty( $_POST ) ) {
    $query = 'action=activity_update,joined_group';
  }
  return $query;
}

add_filter( 'bp_ajax_querystring', 'filtering_activity_default', 999 );
```

This is working for me as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the filters:
[BP Codex](http://codex.buddypress.org/developer/loops-reference/the-activity-stream-loop/)

IN your case, it would be

```
if ( bp_has_activities( 'action=activity_update,joined_group' ) ) :
```

bp_has_activities is used for both Activity and Group Activity.

So if you only want to apply the filter to Group Activity, you can either:

- use bp_is_group() to determine if you're on a group page.
- or override the template used for Group Activity.

Comment: I have a activity filtering dropdown. It does't work correctly after I adding this code.

Comment: @Sassi I have the same problem. You got any solution?